# How to scope child to parent object?

Tags: javascript, object, scope, prototype

I got following code:

```
define(function() {

    var core = function() {};
    var module;

    core.prototype.module = {
      setModule: function(name) {
        this.module = name;
        module = name;
      }
    };

    core.prototype.sandbox = {
      getModules: function() {
          // will throw undefined
          console.log(this._module);
          // will maybe not throw an error?
          console.log(modules);
      }
    };

});

define(['kernel'], function(Kernel) {
    var sampleCore = new Core();
    sampleCore.setModule('test');
    sampleCore.getModules();
});
```

**As you see I can't access the other namespace with this approach. Is there another way to access this.module somehow?**

Regards

Comment: I think your this is scoped to setmodule/getmodule. Make a var that = this in the core and then use that.module?

Comment: @zladuric could you provide an example so I can mark it as answer?

Comment: There, add it. I didn't try this though, so test it first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setting a parameter for the object?:

```
core.sandbox = {
    register: function(obj, name) {
        console.log( obj.module );
    }
};

var a = new core.module.load(/* ..., .... */);

core.sandbox.register( a );
```

Comment: is it possible to bind an object to this? Something like var parent = { child: {}.bind(this) } ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Isn't that what I've just shown you? :-)

Comment: you can't reference to core! Core is getting instanced with new Core(). So that youre reference isn't valid anymore...

Comment: Better but not optimal. I check out if setting the namespace up in .prototype solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

Use `core.module._modules`

```
core.sandbox = {
  register: function(name) {
      var modules = core.module._modules;
  }
};
```

Comment: This will get at the leatest to a problem when instancing core

Answer (score 0):

As I've said in a comment, maybe you can add a *that* variable to the core object, so that the other functions have something common to get a hold on?

```
define(function() {
    var core = function() {
    var that = this;
    };
    var module;
    core.prototype.module = {
      setModule: function(name) {
        that.module = name;
        module = name;
      }
    };

    core.prototype.sandbox = {
      getModules: function() {
          console.log(that.module);
      }
    };

});
```